# Apollo stopped working even though it was never launched

Tags: cyanogenmod

I'm running a custom CM10 ROM built for the Lenovo Ideapad K1. The ROM includes Apollo as the default music player. For a while now at seemingly random intervals, a

> Apollo has stopped working

modal dialog box would suddenly pop up, even when Apollo was never launched. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) Apollo. It might be running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Apollo could be running a background service. The crash might be happening because of some broken code. This can be fixed with a fresh install

Try the links here : [Apollo](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2196385)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the app data and clearing the cache. To do this, go to the app view, open the menu, "manage apps", choose "apollo", "clear data", and "clear cache". This method worked for me.